# Is it accurate, in Python, to say that we "override" the behavior of a built-in operator?

Tags: python, oop, operator-overloading, operators

In *"Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist"*, the author states:

> For built-in types, there are relational operators (`<`, `>`, `==`, etc.)
>   that compare values and determine when one is greater than, less than,
>   or equal to another. For programmer-defined types, we can override the
>   behavior of the built-in operators by providing a method named `__lt__`,
>   which stands for "less than".

and here is the code for `__lt__` method implemented for `Card`:

```
 # inside class Card:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        t1 = self.suit, self.rank
        t2 = other.suit, other.rank
        return t1 < t2
```

But `__lt__` was not defined for `Card` before, so how do we override its behavior? We here define a new behavior for `__lt__` to make it work with `Card` objects. So, `__lt__` still works for numbers, strings, etc. (all of this is as far as I know).

Am I wrong to say that the author (whose work I deeply admire) should not have used "override"?

Comment: No you "override" the `__lt__` of `object`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, you "*override*" the `__lt__` of `object`.

If you take a look at the **functions defined on an `object()`**:

```
>>> dir(object())
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

(there is an `'__lt__'` in the list).

So that means that in the definition of `object` the `__lt__` is defined:

```
class object:

    # ...

    def __lt__(self,value):
        """Return self<value."""
        # base implementation: objects are not comparable in Python 3
        return NotImplemented
```

Now if you write a class `Card`, you **always inherit from `object`** (even if you did not mention it). So if you define your own `__lt__`, you **override the `object.__lt__` definition**.

In other words, if you write:

```
class Card:

    # ...

    def __lt__(self, other):
        t1 = self.suit, self.rank
        t2 = other.suit, other.rank
        return t1 < t2
```

the *Method Resolution Order (MRO)* of `Card` will be:

```
>>> Card.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Card'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Meaning that if you call `x.__lt__` on a `Card` object `x`, it will first look for an `__lt__` in `Card`, but if it cannot find one, it will *fallback* on `object` and look for an `__lt__` over there. So your `__lt__` "hides" the original `__lt__`.

As you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__). The `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__gt__` and `__ge__` are *rich comparison methods*:

> These are the so-called "rich comparison" methods. The correspondence between operator symbols and method names is as follows: `x<y` calls `x.__lt__(y)`, `x<=y` calls `x.__le__(y)`, `x==y` calls `x.__eq__(y)`, `x!=y` calls `x.__ne__(y)`, `x>y` calls `x.__gt__(y)`, and `x>=y` calls `x.__ge__(y)`.
>
> A *rich comparison* method may return the singleton `NotImplemented` if it does not implement the operation for a given pair of arguments. By convention, `False` and `True` are returned for a successful comparison. However, these methods can return any value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an if statement), Python will call `bool()` on the value to determine if the result is true or false.

Comment: Note that `dir()` returns attributes of an object by going through its class and its bases, so if  `dir()` is returning an item for an object then it doesn't necessarily means it's defined on that object itself. You probably want to use  `vars()`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: yes but since `object` is the root class, we know it is not inherited and furthermore since `__lt__` is a function, the `self.function` will construct a function where the first value is filled in.

Comment: What I meant is saying *because there is an `'__lt__'` in the list means `object` defines `__lt__`* gives a wrong impression. It's true for `object` but not in general.

Comment: Thank you, Willem! But the author says: "we can override the behavior of the built-in operators." Is he right? Don not we here override the behavior of the method? Isn't the built-in `<` defined for `Card` and a `TypeError` occurs when one or two of its arguments are of type `Card`? Doesn't it do its usual behavior on other types (i.e. it hasn't been overriden)?

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib" I would say the `<` is **not** overridden, since its behavior remains the same: calling `__lt__` in the left operand and returning the `bool(..)` of that result, or raising an error if the `__lt__` returns a `NotImplemented`...